# Which should I use? SQL Triggers or Cron Jobs?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, triggers

I am working on a scheduling system that allows for content managers to add content that will go live at a later set date. My SQL/PHP knowledge is not the greatest and after some extensive research I am finding it difficult to figure the best option to use when building this system. Should I use Cron Jobs? or SQL Triggers?

I am looking to make it so I can also execute some PHP along with the SQL commands that will set the content to live.

Comment: Cron jobs work in the background at (regular) intervals you've set it as. Triggers on the other hand, execute when something "triggers" an event. The choice is yours. Read up on triggers if you haven't already http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html *"This statement creates a new trigger. A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table."*

Comment: If you want to execute PHP code then you can't use triggers (at least on their own). Also, you have more control and are able to add more control by using a cron task.

Answer (score 3):

I would use neither. I'd have a 'goLive' datetime and a 'retire' datetime for each piece of content. Then when you select which content to show, you'd have a where clause like this

```
where current timestamp between goLive and retire
```

Then your content appears at the 'goLive' time and disappears at the 'retire' time.

Comment: although if anything else needs to occur before content transitions in to a live status then this approach would leave more complexity in the database (which may be more desirable, flexible and controllable when handled outside of the database)

Comment: This won't work as well for what I need. However this is something I haven't thought of and will keep in mind in future stuff I do. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the responses, all of it has been super useful in helping me come to a conclusion. I will be using Cron Jobs to get this specific job done.